# Creating a header with logo using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

Iam pretty new to LateX and iam trying to display an image in the header using
fancyhdr. Iam also using django to create a template, this is what I got:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% load l10n %}
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\author{Energiemanagementsystem}
\title{Energiebericht}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegrapics[scale=0.5]{ {{stammdaten.bild.path}} }}


\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Text}
Text


\end{document}
{% endautoescape %}
```

And this is what I get out of the log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\f@ncyolh ->\includegrapics
                            [scale=0.5]{ "/var/opt/energiemanagement/media/l...
l.38 \newpage

?
! Emergency stop.
```

What is LateX trying to tell me? Did I do something wrong with the Header or the Syntax? I dont know what to make out of  this.

Comment: Maybe the quote on the picture path into the includegraphics is not understood by tex.

Comment: Hi and welcome, you need to put the whole argument in an extra pair of braces to protext the brackets.

Comment: Do you want old or new hyphenation rules for the german language? Try `ngerman`

Comment: But most importantly, and i can't stress this enough, write `includegraphics` correctly.

Comment: Yes this was one part - I tried it with a hard coded path and without the quotes - this gives me the logo. And the part with the placeholder gives me ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .JPG .

Comment: Omit the file extension and run pdflatex

Comment: this worked - but the template engine leaves me with trailing whitespaces and latex thinks they belong to the path - I may have to think about something else